# .htaccess redirect exact domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm stuck with a I thought "simple" .htaccess redirection but ... still need your help !

I don't want my domain to be accessible like http://example.com but rather than http://example.com/fr (french default language)

How do I match the exact domain http://example.com ? if there are some parameters after the domain name I don't want the rule to be applied !

I have tried :

```
redirectMatch 301 / http://example.com/fr
```

or

```
    redirectMatch 301 ^http://example.com$ http://example.com/fr
```

But gives me a server error ...

I've also tried :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/fr [R=301,L]
```

but the navigator shows : http://example.com/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/fr/ so the rule is interpreted several times ...

Any advises on how to achieve this "not so simple" :) redirection would be appreciated !